# Maximum of beta-distributed random variables

Tags: statistics

Let $X_i \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ be independent beta-distributed random variables for $i = 1, \ldots, k$.    What can we say about $$X =\max(X_1, \ldots, X_k)?$$ In particular, can we estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that $X$ is approximately distributed like $\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$?  We may assume that $\sum_i \alpha_i + \sum_i \beta_i$ is large if it helps.

We can reduce the question to the case $k =2$, since $$\max(X_1, \ldots, X_k) = \max(\max(\max(X_1, X_2),X_3, \ldots))),$$ although some accuracy might be lost in making successive approximations.  Note also that we have $$P(\max(X_1, X_2) \leq z) = P(X_1 \leq z, X_2 \leq z) = P(X_1 \leq z) P(X_2 \leq z),$$ giving the cumulative distribution function for $X$.

Using Sage I was able to take the case $\alpha_1 = 10,\beta_1 = 15,\alpha_2 = 13,\beta_2 = 12$ and approximate the density function of $X$ pretty well with $\alpha =  16.796, \beta = 14.830$.  See image.

[image]

Context:

This would be useful for the [bandit problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) or  [Monte-Carlo tree search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search).  Suppose you are playing $k$ games $Y_i$, and $Y_i$ is either a win, with probability $p_i$, or a loss.  Then the game $Y$ which consists of a *choice* of one of the games $Y_i$ can be modeled by a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p = \max(p_1, \ldots, p_k)$, since the best strategy is to always choose the game $Y_i$ that has the highest win rate.  If we only have limited information about each $Y_i$ (some samples of each, for example), we can put a prior $p_i \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ on each parameter $p_i$ and try to infer information about $p$ from this.

Comment: How did you obtain the beta distribution parameters for approximating the distribution of the maximum?  Using *Mathematica* and using the method of moments I get $\alpha=16.8681$ and $\beta=14.671$ (although there's not much difference between the two approximations).

Comment: @JimB: I used Sage's find_fit method after computing the density for 100 points.  The parameters I get vary a bit depending on where I put the points.

Comment: If that is a "least squares" approach I don't know why one would want to use such a technique to estimate the parameters of a probability distribution as you don't have a regression situation.

Comment: Are the $X_i$'s independent?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, they are independent. Will edit.

Comment: @JimB Hmm, I don't really see why not.  We can compute the density function of $X$ exactly, and we're trying to approximate it with a curve from a given family.  There are lots of ways to do this - we don't have to infer from sample statistics (although that would also work.)

Comment: There are lots of reasons not to want to use least squares for fitting a probability distribution:  (1) Maybe it's the tail region that is more important for one's objective, (2) the fit depends on the arbitrary set of grid points, (3) There are more standard methods (method of moments, for example).  And I'm sure there are other reasons.  However, I can see using least squares to get starting values for a more standard iterative procedure.

Answer (score 3):

One can certainly find a beta distribution with the same mean and variance as $X$ but whether that is a good enough approximation depends on what you need.

If you only want the probability density function of $X$, then that is

$$\sum _{i=1}^n \left(\frac{x^{a_i-1} (1-x)^{b_i-1} \prod _{j \neq i} \frac{B_x(a_j,b_j)}{B(a_j,b_j)}}{B(a_i,b_i)}\right)$$

where $B(a_i,b_i)$ is the beta function and $B_x (a_i,b_i)$ is the incomplete beta function.

I'm not sure there's a nice compact form for the mean and variance but for specific parameters one can calculate the mean and variance which can be matched to a beta distribution.  Here's some *Mathematica* code to do so:

```
n = 3;
parms = {a[1] -> 1, b[1] -> 6, a[2] -> 4, b[2] -> 7, a[3] -> 4, b[3] -> 5}; 
pdf[x_] := 
  Sum[(x^(a[i] - 1) (1 - x)^(b[i] - 1)/Beta[a[i], b[i]]) Product[Beta[x, a[j], b[j]]/Beta[a[j], b[j]],
   {j, Delete[Range[n], i]}] /. parms, {i, n}];

mean = Integrate[x pdf[x], {x, 0, 1}];
variance = Integrate[x^2 pdf[x], {x, 0, 1}] - mean^2;
sol = N[Solve[{mean == a/(a + b), variance == a b/((a + b)^2 (a + b + 1))}, {a, b}][[1]]]
(* {a -> 6.80319, b -> 6.85957} *)

Plot[{pdf[x], PDF[BetaDistribution[a, b] /. sol, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Actual", "Beta approximation"}]
```

[image: True density and beta distribution approximation]

***Addition:***

To echo @AhmedFasih 's comment below, even the mean for $k=2$ is not simple:

$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\alpha _1+\alpha _2+1\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _1+\beta _1\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _2+\beta _2\right)* \, _3F_2\left(\alpha _1,\alpha _1+\alpha _2+1,1-\beta _1;\alpha _1+1,\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\beta _2+1;1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\alpha _1+1\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _2\right) \Gamma \left(\beta _1\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\beta _2+1\right)}+$$

$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\alpha _1+\alpha _2+1\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _1+\beta _1\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _2+\beta _2\right)*\, _3F_2\left(\alpha _2,\alpha _1+\alpha _2+1,1-\beta _2;\alpha _2+1,\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\beta _1+1;1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\alpha _1\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _2+1\right) \Gamma \left(\beta _2\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\beta _1+1\right)}$$

Comment: Hmm, but this very computationally intensive.  I was hoping for something fast, like a simple formula. For the purposes of Monte-Carlo tree search it would need to be computed a very large number of times.

Comment: Are you sure that is the PDF of the maximum?
My simulations don't agree with it

Comment: @Itay  Posting your simulation code and results would be a good answer.

Comment: @Itay one source of confusion that I suspect is your math library's incomplete Beta function being regularized vs not. Scipy's [betainc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.betainc.html) is regularized so its return values are divided by the Beta already—I didn't have to divide by the Beta—whereas JimB's expression uses the non-regularized version. Here's my Python code showing the excellent match between Jim's expression and Monte Carlo https://gist.github.com/fasiha/fe0a79d294f222d060fa6aeff1424db2

Comment: @AhmedFasih Thanks for that!  (Challenging anyone's results is not a bad thing.)

Comment: I deleted my comment above https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3136814 is likely useful for the case when you have two or three Betas, but for the arbitrary case for $k$ random variables, it seems quite difficult to compute the moments of the density you provide 

Comment: For others who wonder how JimB got the density, it follows from ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3679707/expected-maximum-of-beta-random-variables#comment7561291_3679707)) the distribution $F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x] = \mathbb{P}[X_1\leq x,...,X_n\leq x] = \prod_i \mathbb{P}[X_i\leq x] = \prod_i F_{X_i}(x)$ and then applying the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Product_rule&oldid=1119757448#Product_of_more_than_two_factors) and a tiny bit of simplification to get the density $f_X(x) = \sum_i \left( f_{X_i}(x) \prod_{j\neq i} F_{X_j}(x) \right)$